# Creating a 3D Array from an input file?

Tags: c, file, input, std, multidimensional-array

I want to store the following lines from an input file into a 3D Array (excluding the first line.) The first line represents the number of following lines.

3

4 9368 86 843 23224

4 7323 2 2665 2665

8447 47 843 5278 8378 2273

My problem is if I use fscanf, there is no way to tell when there is a newline. Therefore I can't stop scanning and go to the next index in the outermost array. If I use fgets and sscanf, I can only read in the first string of each line (in this case, 4 then 4 then 8447.)

That is because fgets processes an entire line as one string (1D Array,) when I want each line to be processed as a 2D array, and then each stored in an outermost array, resulting in a 3D array.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()` combined with `fgets()` to parse one number at a time. You can do it by advancing a pointer into your string as you parse each number.

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), infile) != 0) {
    const char *p = buf;
    size_t len = strlen(buf);
    int val;
    int n;
    while (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &val, &n) == 1) {
        /*...do something with val */
        p += n;
        if (p >= buf+len) break;
    }
}
```

The `%n` directive provides the number of bytes consumed thus far in the scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char array[16][16][16];
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    int row = atoi(line);
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i<row;++i){
        int col = 0;
        char *p;
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        for(p = strtok(line, " \t\n");p;p=strtok(NULL, " \t\n")){
            strcpy(array[i][col++], p);
        }
        array[i][col][0] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(fp);
    {//check
        for(int i=0;i<row;++i){
            for(int j=0;array[i][j][0];++j)
                printf("%s ", array[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```